# How to delete several elements in an association?

Tags: associations

What is the most efficient way of deleting more than one pairs with known keys in an association?

Please check the following failed and successful examples.

```
as = Association[{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4}]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>
> ```

```
Delete[as, "a"]
```

> ```
> <|"b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>
> ```

```
Delete[as, {"a", "d"}]
```

> Delete::psl: Position specification d in <|a->1,b->2,c->3,d->4|> is not a machine-sized integer or a list of machine-sized integers. >>
>       Delete[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>, {"a", "d"}]

```
Delete[as, {Key["a"], Key["b"]}]
```

> Delete::psl: Position specification Key[b] in <|a->1,b->2,c->3,d->4|> is not a machine-sized integer or a list of machine-sized integers. >>
>
> ```
> Delete[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>, {Key["a"], Key["b"]}]
> ```

```
Delete[as, Flatten@Position[Keys[as], #] & /@ {"a", "d"}]
```

> ```
> <|"b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>
> ```

```
bs = KeyDrop[as, {"a", "d"}]; bs
```

> ```
> <|"b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>
> ```

```
KeyDropFrom[as, {"a", "d"}]; as
```

> ```
> <|"b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>
> ```

Comment: Please post code as _code_ not in form of a screenshot. See [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) how to do that

Comment: Use `KeyDrop` not `Delete`.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, for I wished to keep the error messages together with the codes (and outputs). I will check whether I can do that.

Comment: Fold[Delete, as, {"a", "d"}]

Answer (score 5):

**Code:**

```
data = Association[{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4}];
KeyDrop[data, {"a", "b"}]
```

**Output:**

```
(*<|"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>*)
```

**Reference:**
[KeyDrop](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyDrop.html)

**Guide:**
[Associations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html)

Answer (score 3):

all,

Here I try to paste the code as suggested by Sascha, and I include the suggestion from Kuba. Much thanks. (The error messages does not look right, though. If you know how to show them correctly among codes, please teach me that! Thanks!)

```
as = Association[{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4}]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>
> ```

```
 Delete[as, "a"]
```

> ```
> <|"b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>
> ```

```
 Delete[as, {"a", "d"}]
```

> During evaluation of In[69]:= Delete::psl: Position specification d in <|a->1,b->2,c->3,d->4|> is not a machine-sized integer or a list of machine-sized integers. >>
>
> ```
> Delete[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>, {"a", "d"}]
> ```

```
 Delete[as, {Key["a"], Key["b"]}]
```

> During evaluation of In[70]:= Delete::psl: Position specification Key[b] in <|a->1,b->2,c->3,d->4|> is not a machine-sized integer or a list of machine-sized integers. >>
>
> ```
> Delete[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>, {Key["a"], Key["b"]}]
> ```

```
 Delete[as, Flatten@Position[Keys[as], #] & /@ {"a", "d"}]
```

> ```
> <|"b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>
> ```

```
 KeyDrop[as, {"a", "d"}]; as
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>
> ```

```
 KeyDropFrom[as, {"a", "d"}]; as
```

> ```
> <|"b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>
> ```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/44392)

Comment: @MarcoB Isn't the OP trying to answer his own question?  That's how it reads to me anyway.

Comment: Is the edit I;ve done, something you were after?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I had read it that the OP was trying to include the code that was originally included as a screenshot in the question.  Looking again, I see Kuba's solution is included.  So I think half of it is meant to be an edit of the question and half could be an answer.  -- It would be nice if the OP would edit it.  I find it a bit confusing in its current form.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see your point, and I noticed that the code has been poured into the question as well; perhaps the OP should remove their old code from this answer, and leaving only the new code representing a solution to their problem.